# Problem with stored procedure for queue position management on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am creating a database of local library book queue on PostgreSQL. The library members can insert queue into the table book_queue for his or her desired queue position based on the book that he or she wants because certain books are not always available to every member. I am having problem with the QueuePosition attribute from the stored procedure that I created. The ERD is shown below:

[image]

Below is the code used to create the three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE member
(
    memberID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    first_name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE book
(
     bookID int PRIMARY KEY, 
     book_name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE book_queue
(
    MemberID int NOT NULL,
    BookID int NOT NULL,
    DateAddedInQueue TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
    QueuePosition int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT BookQueue_MemberId_BookID_PK 
        PRIMARY KEY (MemberId,BookID),
    CONSTRAINT BookQueue_MemberId_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (MemberId) REFERENCES Member(MemberId),
    CONSTRAINT BookQueue_BookID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES book(BookID)
);
```

These are the values inserted into the tables:

```
insert into member values(1, 'John');
insert into member values(2, 'Sam');
insert into member values(3, 'Bob');
insert into member values(4, 'Alex');
insert into book values(1, 'Fahrenheit 451');
insert into book values(2, 'Catch-22');
insert into book values(3, 'Of Mice and Men');
insert into book values(4, 'The Grapes of Wrath');
insert into book values(5, 'The Call of the Wild');
```

Below, I have created a stored procedure to add member's desired books queue position to the table `Book_Queue`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_to_queue(member_id INT, book_id INT, queue_position INT) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE 
    current_position int;
    BEGIN

    -- Check if the book already exists in the queue
    SELECT queueposition INTO current_position FROM book_queue WHERE memberid = member_id AND bookid = book_id;
    
    IF current_position IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- book already exists, update the position
        IF queue_position < current_position THEN
            -- Move book up the queue
            UPDATE book_queue SET queueposition = queueposition + 1 WHERE memberid = member_id AND queueposition >= queue_position AND queueposition < current_position;
            UPDATE book_queue SET queueposition = queue_position WHERE memberid = member_id AND bookid = book_id;
        ELSIF queue_position > current_position THEN
            -- Move book down the queue
            UPDATE book_queue SET queueposition = queueposition - 1 WHERE memberid = member_id AND queueposition > current_position AND queueposition <= queue_position;
            UPDATE book_queue SET queueposition = queue_position WHERE memberid = member_id AND bookid = book_id;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        -- book does not exist, add to the queue
        
        INSERT INTO book_queue (memberid, bookid, dateaddedinqueue, queueposition) VALUES (member_id, book_id, CURRENT_DATE, queue_position);
        
        -- Adjust position of other book in the queue
        UPDATE book_queue SET queueposition = queueposition + 1 WHERE memberid = member_id AND queueposition >= queue_position;
        
        -- Handle gaps in the queue
        UPDATE book_queue SET queueposition = queueposition - 1 WHERE memberid = member_id AND queueposition > (SELECT queueposition FROM book_queue WHERE memberid = member_id ORDER BY queueposition ASC LIMIT 1);
    END IF;
end;$$
```

Shown below, I call the stored procedure to add four members desired books to the queue and its positions. All four members want to add the same book_ID (book_ID=4). Member 3 and Member 4 have **purposely put the wrong gapped queue position 10 and 15 for the queue**. After calling the procedure add_to_queue, **it is giving me the wrong output** with queueposition as 2, 2, 11, 16, circled in red below.

```
call add_to_queue(1, 4, 1);
call add_to_queue(2, 4, 1);
call add_to_queue(3, 4, 10);
call add_to_queue(4, 4, 15);
```

[image]

However, I would like the output for queue position to be 1, 2, 3, 4, **highlighted below**:

[image]

What can I do to edit my stored procedure add_to_queue, so that it aligns the queue position to 1, 2, 3, 4 for all four book members for book_id=4? The four members all want book_id=4 to be added to the queue list. The procedure is giving me the wrong output. I am not seeing what I am doing wrong with my stored procedure. What can I fix on my stored procedure, so that the queueposition is 1, 2, 3, 4 after calling below?

```
call add_to_queue(1, 4, 1);
call add_to_queue(2, 4, 1);
call add_to_queue(3, 4, 10);
call add_to_queue(4, 4, 15);
```

Comment: You haven't explained how this "queue" (and it is clearly more complex than a classical queue) is supposed to behave. Is the position unique for all entries or just per person (or not at all). Are gaps allowed? Does it always start at 1 (so lending a book would renumber the whole view)? We can't tell from the function code because if that was correct you wouldn't be asking this question

Comment: Is the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info) tag related to the question?

Comment: A queue position seems to be something that should be calculated dynamically - as people can presumably join and leave the queue. Why not insert timestamps into dateaddedinqueue and calculate their position from that? It’s a bit like not holding a person’s age in a database, instead you hold their DoB and calculate their age when required